# Can't set a permanent static IP address through network/interfaces

Tags: networking, dhcp

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on a laptop computer that always lives in my house and for which I would like to set a static IP address (so I can access it remotely). I have tried following steps outlined here: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html

Specifically, I opened `/etc/network/interfaces` as root and added something of the form

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.111
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Then I ran

```
sudo ifdown eth0
sudo ifup eth0
```

I also leased my computer this address though the router I am using.

When I check the ip address though through `ifconfig`, it looks like some random ip address gets assigned anyway? Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

edit 1: corrected ip addresses. Note also that the address assigned s 192.168.0.2

edit 2: the output of `route -n`

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0
```

edit 3: 
the content of `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback

 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet static
 address 192.168.0.111
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 192.168.0.1
```

the inet address and mask of every device as listed by `ifconfig -a`:

```
 eth0 inet addr:192.168.0.2 Mask:255.255.255.0
 lo   inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
 wlan0 inet addr:192.168.0.7 inet addr:192.168.0.7
```

Comment: what ip gets assigned ?

Comment: right now its essentially assigned 10.0.0.2 (I'n not providing my actual IP, but the last digits are the same as in real life)

Comment: Routers use network address translation (NAT) so the LAN IP gives no useful information about the "real life" (public) network address. OTOH it **might** give information that would help those who are trying to answer your question.

Comment: Oh, I see. Um, in that case replace al of the 10.0.0.x with 192.168.0.x in the above posts

Comment: So, the address has the correct network portion   but an incorrect address on the network? Does your default route get assigned correctly?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but could how can I tell if my default route is assigned correctly? The output of route -n has been added above, if that helps at all.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  (Just use plain English like: I want to connect to my brother's machine in another state from my machine) Do you know the difference between an external and an internal IP address?  Do you know what DHCP reservation is?

Comment: The default route is the one with a destination of "default" when you do `route`. With `route -n`, it's 0.0.0.0. Can you post the full contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`, including indentation, and the portion of `ifconfig -a` that shows the ip address and netmask for every network device? It looks like you're getting assigned an address via DHCP, somehow.

Comment: Mark Plotnik -- I have posted the information you requested. Thanks for bearing with me on this.

Comment: Fabby -- My goal is to allow myself to SSH to my laptop in my home, which is behind a netgear router from work.  I am learning about all of these topics as I go.

Comment: If you run `nmcli dev list iface eth0` , does it show `GENERAL.NM-MANAGED: yes` as well as the incorrect IP address 192.168.0.2 in a `DHCP4` line? If so, your eth0 is being managed by NetworkManager, not by the settings in `/etc/network/interface`, and NetworkManager has been configured to use DHCP.

Comment: Mark Plotnick - You are correct on both counts. This explains why things aren't working and should get me started on solving the problem. I'll update with more details once I get things working or get stuck again.

Answer (score 1):

As Mark Plotnick pointed out in the comments `/etc/network/interfaces` does nothing if the system is using Network Manager.

I instead set a static IP for the wired address in the Network Manager (Connections Menu ⇒ Edit Connections) and things now seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is going to be reverting your machines eth0 back to dhcp.
 (Use the gui app to delete the configuration file if possible).

If your machine is set to static ip, but your router has a dhcp lease for it, it's going to cause hell...

Once your local machine is set to dhcp, configure your router to maintain a dhcp lease for the laptop. (Check the MAC address you already set and make sure it's right.)

After you get basic connectivity back,  then you will set up port forwarding on your router to be able to access your laptop externally.   Unless you happen to have a business grade connection from your ISP your going to need to setup dynDNS as well.  (so far a topic for another session).

Comment: Actually, I'm having no connectivity problems right now, even with the changes to the interfaces file. It seems like if I just remove the lines I added to the file, everything works as normally for DHCP. I have asked the router to maintain a dhcp lease for the laptop but even so, it seems to arbitrarily assign the IP address. That is why I was trying to set up the static IP. In fact, I can temporarely get things to work by assigning the ip address with ifconfig, but everything undoes itself within a day and stops working.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean you didn't have connectivity.   Once everything is back to a "baseline" type of thing.  If the router is still assigning random Addresses check the MAC (physical) address assigned the lease to, for a typo.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I've re-entered the MAC address dozens of times and checked frequently. Pretty sure there are no typos at least not every time I experience this problem.